# zsh: command not found: code (Ubuntu for Windows)

Tags: ubuntu, windows-10, visual-studio-code

I have this inconvinient with my Ubuntu terminal in Windows 10.

I want to run my command "code ." but it says that the command is not found. The thing is that it works on Windows cmd, but I want to be able to use it in Ubuntu terminal anyways.

So I looked the solution up in the internet, an it said to go to VSCode, press CTRL+SHIFT+P and search "code command" or something like that. I did it, but it says "No command matching".

I uninstalled and reinstalled VSCode, (PATH was checked in the installation as some people might ask) and same issue.

Other people said on the Internet something about adding Visual Studio Code's PATH in the terminal, but I have no clue.

Could you help me out? I'm stuck.

Comment: Plenty of tutorials out there, however assuming you're using WSL, the command you want in VScode is `ctrl+shift+p` and then `Terminal: Select Default Shell` and then in the list that comes up, select WSL bash.

Comment: Doesn't come up

Comment: Do you have [this extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode-remote.remote-wsl) installed?

Answer (score 2):

For those who are having this issue running so far and Google brought you here, like me:

Maybe you decided not share path variables between WSL and Windows, if so, this error will occurs.

To see if this is the problem run on wsl:

`$cat /etc/wsl.conf`

If this appears on the response, then you are indeed not sharing path variable.

```
[interop]
enabled=true
appendWindowsPath=false
```

VSCode will need its own Windows path on WSL's $PATH variable. To solve the problem, write this on your .zprofile (replace <user.name> with your windows user name)

`export PATH="$PATH:/mnt/c/Users/<user.name>/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/bin"`

You may check your VSCode instalation path if its not default.

After done, close the terminal, open again and try!